# Getting error when trying to unpivot columns in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, unpivot

I'm joining multiple tables together by the same column in each of them (called fema_wo). I want to put all the selected columns into one column and then have another column which says which table it came from (essentially the same thing as R's [pivot_longer()](https://rdrr.io/github/tidyverse/tidyr/man/pivot_longer.html)). I'm getting error `No more data to read from socket` `Vendor Code 17410 Error at line: 1` when i try running this; running version `CORE   11.2.0.4.0  Production` of Oracle

Anyone know why this is happening and a possible fix/suggestion?

See code here:

```sql
select * from (

  select dpd.objectid as id1, ss.objectid as id2, ohp.objectid as id3 , ohs.objectid as id4, ugp.objectid as id5, ugs.objectid as id6,
  s.objectid as id7, t.objectid as id8
  from mvdynamicprotectivedevice dpd
  FULL OUTER JOIN mvsupportstructure ss ON (dpd.fema_wo = ss.fema_wo)
  FULL OUTER JOIN mvoverheadprimaryline ohp ON (dpd.fema_wo = ohp.fema_wo)
  FULL OUTER JOIN overheadsecondaryline ohs ON (dpd.fema_wo = ohs.fema_wo)
  FULL OUTER JOIN mvundergroundprimaryline ugp ON (dpd.fema_wo = ugp.fema_wo)
  FULL OUTER JOIN undergroundsecondaryline ugs ON (dpd.fema_wo = ugs.fema_wo)
  FULL OUTER JOIN mvswitch s ON (dpd.fema_wo = s.fema_wo)
  FULL OUTER JOIN mvtransformer t ON (dpd.fema_wo = t.fema_wo)
  WHERE dpd.fema_wo = 'WBS.F.81109.1.1.2'

)
unpivot (

  objectid
  for objectid
  in (id1, id2, id3, id4, id5, id6, id7, id8)

    );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`UNION ALL` seems simpler:

```
select dpd.objectid as id,
from mvdynamicprotectivedevice dpd
where dpd.fema_wo = 'WBS.F.81109.1.1.2'
union all
select ss.objectid
from mvsupportstructure ss join
     mvdynamicprotectivedevice dpd
     on dpd.fema_wo = ss.fema_wo and dpd.fema_wo = 'WBS.F.81109.1.1.2'
union all
select ohp.objectid
from mvoverheadprimaryline ohp join
     mvdynamicprotectivedevice dpd
     on dpd.fema_wo = ohp.fema_wo and dpd.fema_wo = 'WBS.F.81109.1.1.2'
. . . ;
```

My guess is that your outer join is significantly multiplying the number of rows, due to multiple matches in each table.

Comment: Oh this is awesome, I totally misunderstood what ```union all``` did. I neglected to mention though, there are about 8 other fields I need to include in the query; that is why I was using ```FULL OUTER JOIN```, as some work orders may not have all features on them, in-which case I want nulls returned for those features.